# Efficiently converting ID-value pair of arrays into array for each ID - NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

**Problem:**

I have a dataset of multiple binary neurons recorded in parallel. Whenever a neuron fires, the time of fire is recorded into a NumPy array, and the ID of the recorded neuron is recorded in a secondary NumPy array. For example, if [0.25, 0.31, 0.41, 0.50] is the array of firing times, and [0, 5, 2, 1] is the array of IDs, then neuron 0 fired at 0.25s, neuron 5 fired at 0.31s, and so on.

**Expected Output:**

Instead of this, **I want an array for each neuron, with the times it fired.**
So, if neuron 0 fired at [0.25, 1.25, 4.0], then that'll be the array for neuron 0, and each neuron will have its own array.

**What I've tried:**

The brute force approach of creating an array for each neuron and looping through and appending to the correct array will work, but appending is slow.

A better approach than doing an individual element loop is using `.where()` to get the locations of each ID, and then indexing into the array of times:

```
    individual_times = []
    for i in range(minindex, maxindex+1):
        i_indices = np.where(indices==i)[0]
        individual_times.append(times[i_indices])
```

This is not very fast, though, so if there's a faster way to do this, I'd love to know. Thanks!

**Edit: Reproducible input and output:**

```
#input:
times = np.array([0.25, 0.52, 1.25, 4.0, 6.78])
IDs = np.array([0, 1, 0, 0, 2])
#expected output
individual_times = [np.array([0.25, 1.25, 4.0]), np.array([0.52]), np.array([6.78])]
```

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: @Epsi95 question edited to clarify.

Comment: where does `1.25, 4.0` come from? Please give reproducible input and output

Comment: @Epsi95 apologies, it's there now, please let me know if there's anything else I can add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try boolean masking

```py
times = np.array([0.25, 0.52, 1.25, 4.0, 6.78])
IDs = np.array([0, 1, 0, 0, 2])

individual_times = []
for unique_ids in np.sort(np.unique(IDs)):
    individual_times.append(times[IDs == unique_ids])
    
print(individual_times)
```

```
[array([0.25, 1.25, 4.  ]), array([0.52]), array([6.78])]
```